# Inverting an isometric projection?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, projective-geometry

I'm trying to invert a function that takes points on a 2-d plane to an isometric projection of that plane. This function is encoded as follows (as part of the [Isomer](http://jdan.github.io/isomer/) library):

```
Isomer.prototype._translatePoint = function(point) {
  /**
   * X rides along the angle extended from the origin
   * Y rides perpendicular to this angle (in isometric view: PI - angle)
   * Z affects the y coordinate of the drawn point
   */
  var xMap = new Point(point.x * this.transformation[0][0],
                       point.x * this.transformation[0][1]);

  var yMap = new Point(point.y * this.transformation[1][0],
                       point.y * this.transformation[1][1]);

  var x = this.originX + xMap.x + yMap.x;
  var y = this.originY - xMap.y - yMap.y - (point.z * this.scale);
  return new Point(x, y);
};
```

On my reading, this is basically a set of simultaneous equations (ignoring `point.z` since I would like to map to the projected plane z=0):

```
x = origin.x + xmap.x + ymap.x
y = origin.y - xmap.y - ymap.y
```

Substituting in the values for `xmap` and `ymap` we have

```
x = o.x + (point.x * tx[0][0]) + (point.y * tx[1][0])
y = o.y - (point.x * tx[0][1]) - (point.y * tx[1][1])
```

(where o is the origin and tx is the transformation matrix.)

We can encode this in single-letter variables as follows

```
x = c + ae + bg
y = d - af - bh
```

where

```
  a = point.x
  b = point.y
  c = origin.x
  d = origin.y
  e = tx[0][0]
  f = tx[0][1]
  g = tx[1][0]
  h = tx[1][1]
```

To invert the function, I would think we want to solve this set of equations for a and b. Wolfram Alpha gives me the following solution:

```
a = ch + dg - gy - hx / fg - eh
b = -cf - de + ey + fx / fg - eh
```

And this actually looks reasonable. The common divisor term looks to be the determinant of the transformation matrix. For what it's worth here is the code relating to the construction of this matrix:

```
this.transformation = [
    [
      this.scale * Math.cos(this.angle),
      this.scale * Math.sin(this.angle)
    ],
    [
      this.scale * Math.cos(Math.PI - this.angle),
      this.scale * Math.sin(Math.PI - this.angle)
    ]
  ];
```

The transformation matrix is precalculated and always seems to take on the values

```
[[60.62177826491071,34.99999999999999],
 [-60.62177826491071,34.99999999999999]].
```

Comment: I think you may have gotten a sign wrong when you substituted in the values for xmap and ymap (I'm not sure, because I didn't totally follow what you were doing). And if so, that sign error carries through to the denominator, which would then be (tx[0][0] * tx[1][1]) - (tx[0][1] * tx[1][0]). *This* is in fact the determinant of the matrix (what you have written is the permanent), and is nonzero.

Comment: @rogerl thanks so much for taking a look!

Comment: Have tried to update to reflect progress, it's nearly projecting correctly now but is somewhat distorted...

Comment: This looks more like a question for SO, Could you please clarify how you are verifying your results? This could potentially be a problem of your testing and not the math behind it.

Comment: Actually yeah at this point the math is correct, and visually inspecting it seems only to be off by a constant. Feel free to close/delete this.

Comment: can you clarify what the constant was off by, this is a useful question for people looking for isometric projection formulas (like me)

Comment: It was off by 4 or so in the y-coordinate of the projected plane. I can try to write an answer clarifying some of this.